How can I populate a select dropdown with department names in a React component?
I am using mongodb for database. There is a collection named "departments" with property name, description.
In React I've JobDescriptionEdit.jsx below but don't show department name in select dropdown. Here shows all department name. But I need to show exact department name which I entered during create job description
And in console I found department is undefined.
import axios from "axios";
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import { useNavigate, useParams } from "react-router-dom";
import { toast } from "react-toastify";
import "react-toastify/dist/ReactToastify.css";

const JobDescriptionEdit = () => {
  const { id } = useParams(); // Get the job description ID from the URL
  const [positionId, setPositionId] = useState("");
  const [departmentId, setDepartmentId] = useState("");
  const [jobDescription, setJobDescription] = useState("");
  const [isApproved, setIsApproved] = useState(false);
  const [departments, setDepartments] = useState([]);
  const [positions, setPositions] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true); // Loading state
  const navigate = useNavigate();

  useEffect(() => {
    // Fetch departments and positions data
    const fetchDepartmentsAndPositions = async () => {
      try {
        const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
        if (!token) {
          toast.error("Please login to access department and position data.");
          return;
        }

        const [deptResponse, posResponse] = await Promise.all([
          axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/departments", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }),
          axios.get("http://localhost:3000/api/v1/positions", {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }),
        ]);

        console.log("Departments data:", deptResponse.data.departments);
        console.log("Positions data:", posResponse.data.positions);

        setDepartments(deptResponse.data.departments);
        setPositions(posResponse.data.positions);
      } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error fetching departments and positions data:", error);
        toast.error("Error fetching departments and positions data");
      } finally {
        setLoading(false); // Set loading to false after data is fetched
      }
    };

    fetchDepartmentsAndPositions();
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    // If in edit mode, fetch job description data and populate form fields
    if (id) {
      const fetchJobDescription = async () => {
        try {
          const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
          if (!token) {
            navigate("/login");
            return;
          }

          const response = await axios.get(
            `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/jobdescriptions/${id}`,
            {
              headers: {
                Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
              },
            }
          );

          const { positionId, departmentId, jobDescription, isApproved } =
            response.data.jobDescription;

          console.log("Fetched job description:", response.data.jobDescription);

          setPositionId(positionId);
          setDepartmentId(departmentId);
          setJobDescription(jobDescription);
          setIsApproved(isApproved);
        } catch (error) {
          console.error("Error fetching job description data:", error);
          toast.error("Error fetching job description data");
          if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
            navigate("/login");
          }
        }
      };
      fetchJobDescription();
    }
  }, [id, navigate]);

  const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
      if (!token) {
        navigate("/login");
        return;
      }

      const updateBy = null;
      const approvedBy = null;

      if (id) {
        // If in edit mode, update existing job description
        await axios.patch(
          `http://localhost:3000/api/v1/jobdescriptions/${id}`,
          {
            positionId,
            departmentId,
            jobDescription,
            isApproved,
            updateBy,
            approvedBy,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        toast.success("Job description updated successfully");
      } else {
        // If in create mode, create new job description
        await axios.post(
          "http://localhost:3000/api/v1/jobdescriptions",
          {
            positionId,
            departmentId,
            jobDescription,
            isApproved,
            updateBy,
            approvedBy,
          },
          {
            headers: {
              Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
            },
          }
        );
        toast.success("Job description created successfully");
      }
      navigate("/job-description"); // Redirect to job descriptions page after submission
    } catch (error) {
      console.error("Error submitting job description:", error);
      toast.error("Error submitting job description");
      if (error.response && error.response.status === 401) {
        navigate("/login");
      }
    }
  };

  if (loading) {
    return <div>Loading...</div>; // Render loading message while fetching data
  }

  return (
    <div className="min-h-screen flex flex-col">
      <div className="max-w-lg px-10 w-full">
        <h1 className="text-2xl font-bold my-8">
          {id ? "Edit Job Description" : "Create Job Description"}
        </h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              className="block text-sm font-medium mb-2"
              htmlFor="departmentId"
            >
              Department
            </label>
            <select
              id="departmentId"
              value={departmentId}
              onChange={(e) => setDepartmentId(e.target.value)}
              className="select select-bordered w-full"
              required
            >
              <option value="">Select a department</option>
              {departments.map((dept) => (
                <option key={dept._id} value={dept._id}>
                  {dept.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              className="block text-sm font-medium mb-2"
              htmlFor="positionId"
            >
              Position
            </label>
            <select
              id="positionId"
              value={positionId}
              onChange={(e) => setPositionId(e.target.value)}
              className="select select-bordered w-full"
              required
            >
              <option value="">Select a position</option>
              {positions.map((pos) => (
                <option key={pos._id} value={pos._id}>
                  {pos.name}
                </option>
              ))}
            </select>
          </div>

          <div className="mb-4">
            <label
              className="block text-sm font-medium mb-2"
              htmlFor="jobDescription"
            >
              Job Description
            </label>
            <textarea
              id="jobDescription"
              value={jobDescription}
              onChange={(e) => setJobDescription(e.target.value)}
              className="textarea textarea-bordered w-full"
              required
            ></textarea>
          </div>
          <div className="mb-4">
            <label className="block text-sm font-medium mb-2">
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                checked={isApproved}
                onChange={(e) => setIsApproved(e.target.checked)}
                className="checkbox"
              />
              Approved
            </label>
          </div>
          <div className="flex justify-between">
            <button
              type="button"
              className="btn btn-sm btn-secondary"
              onClick={() => navigate("/job-description")}
            >
              Cancel
            </button>
            <button type="submit" className="btn btn-sm btn-primary">
              {id ? "Update Job Description" : "Create Job Description"}
            </button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default JobDescriptionEdit;


I want to show the department name in the select dropdown.

Did you tried logging departments ?

Yes, all department names are shown there. But I want to get the exact department name which I entered during create job description.

Please add the response/collection (departments) received from MongoDB in the above question.

Please show the code where you are populating department.  Note: if you are fetching data from a remote system, then you are likely facing "asynchronous code" and you'll need to deal with it appropriately.  Your component will render before the data arrives, so you need to handle that case and then the component will render later once the data has arrived (assuming that department is a state variable and that you are populating the state variable with the "set state" function).

@GregFenton For your reference, I've added the code there.

why should i not upload images of code/data/errors?

@Taufiqur Rahman Add the output of this deptResponse.data in the above code.
